# upload geojson data to mongodb using mongosh

Tags: mongodb, upload, geospatial, geojson, mongo-shell

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "sql_statement",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 1, "osm_id": "718463", "name": "Devonshire Street", "highway": "trunk", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 8.0, "other_tags": "\"bicycle\"=>\"yes\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"30 mph\",\"ref\"=>\"A665\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.215714, 53.4688332 ], [ -2.2158076, 53.4686872 ], [ -2.2163447, 53.4679631 ], [ -2.2165519, 53.4676764 ], [ -2.2168956, 53.4672164 ], [ -2.2171194, 53.4669126 ], [ -2.2172529, 53.4667313 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 2, "osm_id": "750748", "name": "Conyngham Road", "highway": "residential", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 3.0, "other_tags": "\"abutters\"=>\"residential\",\"lcn\"=>\"yes\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"20 mph\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.2189648, 53.4577115 ], [ -2.2188807, 53.4574696 ], [ -2.2187663, 53.4572319 ], [ -2.2185141, 53.4569357 ], [ -2.2184778, 53.4568999 ], [ -2.2182348, 53.4566605 ], [ -2.218147, 53.4565843 ], [ -2.2174816, 53.4560269 ], [ -2.2174666, 53.4560144 ], [ -2.2171664, 53.4558029 ], [ -2.216945, 53.455658 ], [ -2.2162931, 53.4552271 ], [ -2.2159771, 53.4550358 ], [ -2.2155791, 53.4547811 ], [ -2.2155343, 53.4547524 ], [ -2.2153917, 53.4546611 ], [ -2.2151644, 53.4545248 ], [ -2.2148855, 53.4543331 ], [ -2.2144349, 53.4538731 ], [ -2.2139768, 53.4532958 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 3, "osm_id": "751336", "name": "Rusholme Place", "highway": "residential", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 3.0, "other_tags": "\"lit\"=>\"yes\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"20 mph\",\"sidewalk\"=>\"both\",\"source:name\"=>\"OS_OpenData_Locator\",\"surface\"=>\"asphalt\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.2266453, 53.4576413 ], [ -2.226482, 53.4576826 ], [ -2.2262565, 53.4577383 ], [ -2.225177, 53.4580064 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 4, "osm_id": "751405", "name": "Denison Road", "highway": "residential", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 3.0, "other_tags": "\"abutters\"=>\"residential\",\"maxspeed\"=>\"20 mph\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.2134016, 53.4569789 ], [ -2.2133995, 53.4562855 ], [ -2.2136711, 53.4561013 ], [ -2.2140297, 53.455843 ], [ -2.2144837, 53.4555158 ], [ -2.2146073, 53.4554486 ], [ -2.2148495, 53.4553738 ], [ -2.214919, 53.4553523 ], [ -2.2150012, 53.4553397 ], [ -2.2151738, 53.4553133 ], [ -2.2152485, 53.4553018 ], [ -2.2153973, 53.4552881 ], [ -2.2156165, 53.4552679 ], [ -2.2162931, 53.4552271 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 5, "osm_id": "780145", "name": "Brighton Place", "highway": "service", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 0.0, "other_tags": "\"maxspeed\"=>\"20 mph\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.2315493, 53.4652811 ], [ -2.2311437, 53.4649344 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 249751, "osm_id": "1182561664", "name": null, "highway": "footway", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 0.0, "other_tags": "\"footway\"=>\"sidewalk\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.1410116, 53.5323201 ], [ -2.1407629, 53.5321902 ], [ -2.1407513, 53.5321765 ], [ -2.1407467, 53.5321692 ], [ -2.1407583, 53.5321582 ], [ -2.1411346, 53.5319099 ], [ -2.1412105, 53.5318592 ], [ -2.1413529, 53.5317545 ], [ -2.1415199, 53.5316115 ], [ -2.1416857, 53.5314838 ], [ -2.1420032, 53.53125 ], [ -2.1422519, 53.5310862 ], [ -2.1426493, 53.5308777 ], [ -2.1431348, 53.530642 ], [ -2.1438164, 53.5303152 ], [ -2.1439366, 53.5302618 ], [ -2.1440417, 53.5302181 ], [ -2.1441363, 53.5301882 ], [ -2.1442448, 53.5301723 ], [ -2.1443312, 53.5301743 ], [ -2.144434, 53.5301875 ], [ -2.1445893, 53.5302222 ], [ -2.1452489, 53.5304068 ], [ -2.1452617, 53.5304158 ], [ -2.1452648, 53.5304332 ], [ -2.145215, 53.5305109 ], [ -2.1450808, 53.53076 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 249752, "osm_id": "1182561665", "name": null, "highway": "footway", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 0.0, "other_tags": "\"footway\"=>\"sidewalk\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.1403271, 53.5323202 ], [ -2.1405369, 53.5321821 ], [ -2.140808, 53.531987 ], [ -2.141193, 53.5317128 ], [ -2.1412943, 53.5316318 ], [ -2.1413457, 53.5315804 ], [ -2.1413632, 53.5315527 ], [ -2.1413627, 53.5315437 ], [ -2.141362, 53.5315312 ], [ -2.141334, 53.5315117 ], [ -2.14109, 53.5314118 ], [ -2.1409231, 53.5313549 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gid": 249753, "osm_id": "1182561666", "name": null, "highway": "footway", "waterway": null, "aerialway": null, "barrier": null, "man_made": null, "railway": null, "z_order": 0.0, "other_tags": "\"crossing\"=>\"unmarked\",\"crossing:markings\"=>\"no\",\"footway\"=>\"crossing\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ -2.1413627, 53.5315437 ], [ -2.1414264, 53.5314986 ], [ -2.1414761, 53.5314561 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I have the data in the above farmat now how to upload the data in the mongodb.
I try this but not working:[commonds used to upload the geojson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAhnT.png)
I want that after the upload of the data i can run the spatial queries on it.

Comment: Please post the text of the error rather than uploading/linking a screenshot of it

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here assist in the full resolution of the problem. But the specific error that you are getting is clear.

We see in your screenshot that the prompt you have when attempting your command is

```
admin>
```

This suggests that you are already connected to the database in a shell session (via `mongosh`). If I attempt the first part of your command from inside a shell session I get a similar error:

```
 test> mongoimport --db
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:14)

> 1 | mongoimport --db
    |               ^
  2 |
```

This is because `mongoimport` is a *command line utility* rather than a function to be called from inside the shell. As [the documentation states](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#syntax):

> Run `mongoimport` from the system command line, not the `mongo` shell.

If it is just a single document that you wish to insert, then you could copy and paste it into a `db.points_data.insertOne(<here>)` command.

As an aside, it is generally not recommended to put user data into the `admin` database. That database is used for other internal functionality, so best to use a namespace (database) dedicated to your purpose.

If you have further trouble importing the data after making this adjustment then that would warrant a new question.

Comment: I also add the bin folder path in my Environmental variable paths but the mongo is not working in the commond line. and the second thing is I have the data in millions points, lines and polygons can't be added using db.points_data.insertOne(<here>). because it will add all data as a single entity in collection. I want to put each feature as a unique entity. so that I have to run the spatial queries on them.